# Get jni::JNIEnv from jni_sys::JNIEnv

Tags: java, rust, java-native-interface

I'm trying to execute a static method, and my best bet is via the `jni::JNIEnv`. I must use `jni_sys::JNIEnv`, and can only start off with the later type.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method [`jni::JNIEnv::from_raw`](https://docs.rs/jni/0.19.0/jni/struct.JNIEnv.html#method.from_raw), which allows to wrap an existing raw pointer to `jni_sys::JNIEnv`.